# Run a function on two input lists with purrr

Tags: r, dplyr, lapply, purrr, mapply

I have a `list` L1 and a `data.frame` D2. **L1** contains two data.frames of students on different programmes of study [[1]] and [[2]]

So **L1** is a list of students split by their programme of study (architecture vs engineering). **D2** is a `data.frame` of projects they can choose.

I have a function that takes two inputs (L1[[1]] and D2) and returns a single data.frame but how can I pass the whole list **L1** and the data.frame **D2** to the function and have it work on L1[[1]] + D2 then L1[[2]] + D2.

```
D2<-data.frame(programme=c("Architecture","Architecture","Engineering", "Engineering"), project=c(14,15,19,20))

L1<-data.frame(studentID=c(203,204,205), programme=c("Architecture","Engineering", "Engineering")) %>% group_by(programme) %>% group_split()


F=function(L1,D2){ L1 %>% left_join(D2)}
```

I could do a for-loop or `F(L1[[1]],D2)` and `F(L2[[2]],D2)` but Map(L1,as.list(D2),F) doesn't seem to handle it the way I might have expected.

I'm looking at `purrr::lmap` but this only takes a single list. Has anyone seen something that takes mixed inputs into a function and iterates over each list not over a vector?

Comment: `map(L1, left_join, D2)` should work for you.

Comment: Richie, thank you so much, I really appreciate your help on this! I think I was making it too complicated.

Comment: Which results are you looking for: (1) `list(left_join(L1[[1]], D2), left_join(L1[[2]], D2))` (still a list of two frames, with `D2` joined into each individually); or (2) `left_join(L1[[2]], left_join(L1[[1]], D2))` (a single frame, the result of repeatedly joining)`?

Comment: @r2evans number 1, please.

Comment: Then Ritchie's comment is correct, as is `lapply(L1, left_join, D2)`.